# PayPal Website Payments Pro: Express Checkout: How to Hide "Purchase Details" in Paypal?

Tags: paypal, x-cart

PayPal Website Payments Pro: Express Checkout: How to Hide "Purchase Details" in Paypal in the following page: https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/transactions/details/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. In other words, I don't want the entire invoice or list of goods purchased to be transferred to Paypal. Possible?

Comment: Do you mean 'Website Payments Pro Hosted'? https://imgur.com/uek7JML.png https://imgur.com/WncIzSL.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't know x-cart. However, Paypal can only show what they know, i.e. only the information which has been transferred to them using their APIs.

So the usual method to solve problems like that is to look into the source code of the respective application (in this case: x-cart) and to change the calls to the Paypal APIs accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out elsewhere, so I will share it with others:

It is possible to customize the PHP script that sends the info about the ordered items to PayPal:

Find this: payment/ps_paypal_pro_us.php

Then find this line of code:

```
if (!empty($pp_paypal_totals)) {
```

and change it to:

```
if (false && !empty($pp_paypal_totals)) {
```